# python 3.3 urllib read html in unknown character sets

Tags: python, utf-8, set, character, urllib

i use the following code python 3.3 to read the nyu's home page. however, it show incorrect output in unknown character set. the response header content-type is UTF-8. the code can read other htmls correctly, but not for the nyu page. could you help my why?

```
url='http://www.stern.nyu.edu/'
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0'),
      ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8')]
r=opener.open(url)
r.read().decode('UTF-8')
```

and the result snippet is here:

```
 ¢=¿/JçW®<× 4ô9ïÛ9$*Á¹³÷î·ïõ¡(ÂÄÀPZÓ¯seßVÿ_<ÅsÎF"t¢ÂQý­Mâ°AÈX¨ÕA ¨IØ ³ <ðGÀp«�¾X(ÛìÊß}XkfÌ=] Ð0.|¿v°f©ÛTüAH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is Gzipped, so there's no point in trying to decode it as UTF-8. You can either decompress it yourself:

```
from io import StringIO
import gzip

with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=r) as handle:
    html = handle.read()
```

Or use something like [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), which does it for you:

```
import requests

html = requests.get('http://www.stern.nyu.edu/', headers={
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}).text
```

Comment: one more question. how can i find the response is Gzipped

Comment: @sse: The `Content-Encoding` header will contain `gzip`. Gzip is the most common, but there are a few other compression methods out there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression#Content-Encoding_tokens

Comment: perfect. thanks very much.  one more question. why some pages are gzipped, instead of text/html. for fast loading the page?